# ASIHTTPClasses and iOS6

Tags: ios6, nsxmlparsererrordomain

My app has been working correctly on previous iOS versions. I just upgraded to iOS6 and now the app is returning an error while processing an XML request/response.

The app sends an XML request to a server and receives an XML response, but now the response is empty "<>" causing the NSXMLParser to fail.

Here is how the app is sending the request (this used to work, prior ios6):

```
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];




NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn)
{

    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

}
```

But the response is now empty "<>".

```
 parser error is Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 9.)", path to file is :

/Users/ronluna/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/5BA74D89-1967-4B9E-A1C0-B076F7BB9064/Documents/Menus.xml
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi ive also encountered the same problem. Try changing the format of your xml file to **UTF-8 without BOM** or if you are populating your xml on a server side script try changing the character set to **UTF-8**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you create your NSData object with encoding specified in xml format.
i.e, if xml have utf-8 encoding, the you should have :
    NSData* d = [xmlResponseStrings dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
in your code,
other NSUnicodexxxxx encoding will not work.
Hope this help.